# why I can't find locked table?

Tags: mysql, innodb, locking

I locked 3 innodb tables with write lock

```
lock tables hive.NEXT_COMPACTION_QUEUE_ID write;
lock tables hive.NEXT_LOCK_ID write;
lock tables hive.NEXT_TXN_ID write;
```

I find out which table is locked through SQL

```
SHOW OPEN TABLES WHERE `Database` LIKE 'hive' AND In_use > 0;
```

but only one table (last table I locked) ,why ？

```
+--------------------+----------------------------------------------+--------+-------------+
| Database           | Table                                        | In_use | Name_locked |
+--------------------+----------------------------------------------+--------+-------------+
| hive               | NEXT_TXN_ID                                  |      1 |           0 |
```

but when I want to show the first table which I thought isn't locked,it locks!why? is show open tables not correct?

```
 show create table hive.NEXT_COMPACTION_QUEUE_ID;
ERROR 1100 (HY000): Table 'NEXT_COMPACTION_QUEUE_ID' was not locked with LOCK TABLES
```

Comment: Yikes!  `LOCK TABLES` on InnoDB tables?  Why?

Comment: See if `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your queries are equivalent to the following:

```
UNLOCK TABLES;
lock tables hive.NEXT_COMPACTION_QUEUE_ID write;
UNLOCK TABLES;
lock tables hive.NEXT_LOCK_ID write;
UNLOCK TABLES;
lock tables hive.NEXT_TXN_ID write;
```

> `LOCK TABLES` implicitly releases any table locks held by the current session before acquiring new locks.
>
> — http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables.html

The correct way to lock multiple tables is in a single statement:

```
lock tables hive.NEXT_COMPACTION_QUEUE_ID write,
            hive.NEXT_LOCK_ID write,
            hive.NEXT_TXN_ID write;
```